# Why solid angle is defined as "the two-dimensional angle in three-dimensional space"?

Tags: geometry, solid-angle

In [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_angle) the solid angle is defined as follows:

> In geometry, a solid angle (symbol: Ω) is the two-dimensional angle in three-dimensional space that an object subtends at a point.

Why solid angle is a two dimensional angle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ordinary angle is a measure of the length subtended by a one-dimensional subset of the plane.  For example, an angle of $60^\circ$ is subtended from a point by a $\frac16$ portion of a circle centered at that point.  The $\frac16$ arc that subtends the angle is a **one-dimensional** subset of the two-dimensional plane.

By analogy, a solid angle is subtended by a **two-dimensional** subset of the three-dimensional space.  A solid angle measuring 1 steradian is the solid angle subtended from a point by a certain two-dimensional subset of a sphere centered at that point.

Comment: Can you elaborate the `one-dimensional subset`?

Comment: Sorry, I can't think of anything else to say.  What part of  “The $\frac16$ arc that subtends the angle is a one-dimensional subset” is giving you trouble?  This arc is part of a circle; a circle is a one-dimensional set.

Comment: Do you know what a one-dimensional set is?

Comment: I think the element in one-dimensional set can be expressed with 1 number coordinate (x). By analogy, the element in two-dimensional set can be expressed with 2 number coordinate (x, y). But steradian is 1 number and this makes me confusing.

Comment: A steradian isn't a set, it is a *measure*. A square is two-dimensional,  but it has an area, which measures the square;  the area is just a number.

Comment: I don't know why a circle is a one-dimensional set. Now I think I don't know what's a one-dimensional set.

Comment: Okay, I understand now. Quoted from wikipedia:` In mathematics, the dimension of an object is an intrinsic property independent of the space in which the object is embedded. For example, a point on the unit circle in the plane can be specified by two Cartesian coordinates, but a single polar coordinate (the angle) would be sufficient, so the circle is 1-dimensional even though it exists in the 2-dimensional plane. This intrinsic notion of dimension is one of the chief ways the mathematical notion of dimension differs from its common usages.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22077/discussion-between-wang-zhihao-and-mjd).

Answer (score 1):

On a straight line, the *length* of an object is the *one-dimensional* extent of it.  On a flat plane, the *area* of an object is the *two-dimensional* extent of it.  It is nonetheless given as a single value, and the unit of that value is the square of the unit of length.

Similarly, on a circle, the *angle* subtended by an object is the *one-dimensional* length of the circle "covered" by that object.  On a sphere, the *solid angle* subtended by an object is the *two-dimensional* portion of the sphere "covered" by that object.  It is nonetheless given as a single value.

The unit of solid angle, the steradian, is dimensionless, but it is defined such that the area covered by one steradian on the unit sphere is equal to $1$.  (There are thus $4\pi$ steradians on the sphere.)  This is analogous to the radian, which too is dimensionless, and is defined such that the length covered by one radian on the unit circle is equal to $1$ (so there are $2\pi$ radians in the circle).

Comment: I find it straightforward that the length of a segment is one-dimensional and the area of a polygon is two-dimensional. But I'm still confused with the length of arc and the area of surface.

Comment: Well, let's make it concrete.  Suppose I measure the distance between two points on the Earth to be 6400 km.  That's about the radius of the Earth, and so we say that the arc between those two points _subtends_ one radian (as seen from the center of the Earth).

For solid angles, we look at the area: The continental United States (lower 48 states) has an area of about 8 million square km.  If we square one Earth radius, we get about 40 million square km.  We might therefore say that the continental U.S. _subtends_ about 0.2 steradians (again, as seen from the center of the Earth).